# Prevent showing border of a disabled menu item on mouse hover

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstrip, menustrip

When I hover over a `ToolStripMenuItem`, it shows a border around it even when it is disabled. Is there any property to remove this?

I've looked for properties like `Hover` or `Border` but haven't found anything of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToolStripProfessionalRenderer` draws the border by default using `MenuItemBorder` property of `ProfessionalColorTable`.

To make the border just visible for enabled menu items, you can create your custom `ProfessionalColorTable` and your custom `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer` and add a new `MenuItemEnabledBorder` returning the default border color, and also overriding `MenuItemBorder` to return `Color.Transparent`.

Then in your custom renderer, it's enough to override `OnRenderMenuItemBackground` and draw the border using `MenuItemEnabledBorder` when the item is highlighetd.

**Code**

```
public class MyColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color MenuItemBorder { get { return Color.Transparent; } }
    public Color MenuItemEnabledBorder { get { return base.MenuItemBorder; } }
}

public class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    public MyRenderer() : base(new MyColorTable()) { }
    protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e);
        if (e.Item.Enabled && e.Item.Selected)
        {
            using (var pen = new Pen(((MyColorTable)ColorTable).MenuItemEnabledBorder))
            {
                var r = new Rectangle(2, 0, e.Item.Width - 4, e.Item.Height - 1);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, r);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use the renderer, it's enough to set it as renderer of your tool strip:

```
this.toolStrip1.Renderer = new MyRenderer();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can override `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer` class and pass your colors (if you dont want border pass the original BackColor) to its base class constructor:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication11
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            menuStrip1.Renderer = new CustomColors();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    private class CustomColors : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {
        public CustomColors() : base(new MyColors()) { }
    }

    private class MyColors : ProfessionalColorTable
    {
        public override Color MenuItemSelected
        {
            get { return Color.GreenYellow; }
        }
        public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
        {
            get { return Color.DarkBlue; }
        }
        public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
        {
            get { return Color.Yellow; }
        }
    }
}
```